# How to enable a user to push to a git repository

Tags: php, git

I have a php project on my local machine and want to push it to my staging server. Therefore I setup the git repository on the staging server. In PHPStorm I now want to push:

```
git push mfstaging master
```

I get the error:

> remote: fatal: Unable to create temporary file
>   '/var/www/mfserver.git/./objects/pack/tmp_pack_XXXXXX': Permission
>   denied

Where do I need to make a change? the user on my digital ocean instance is admin and with this user I created the git repo. How do I know push from my local machine to this?

Comment: This is most likely a permission issue on your server/hosting machine, looks like unix based, so try `sudo git push` - It's generally recommended to not do `sudo` anything with `git`, but if it works, you know you have some permission issues to sort.

Comment: Yep. still get the error: but I am somehow stuck and would need a bit more help. How do I now add my local machine user to my git repo?

Comment: You set up get with `git config`. Enter it into console/terminal/shell to see usage. Example: `git config --global user.name "sesc360"`, however, I am still maintaining this is a system level issue.

Comment: Well I think I do not completly understand the process yet. I have a user called admin on my remote server. under this user I created the git repo. I have a different user on my local machine. How and where do I need to give permissions?

Answer (score 0):

**dont** do `sudo git push`.  If youve set it up properly, then your local user will have an ssh key that the root of his machine *shouldnt* have, which means that pushing as root shouldnt authenticate.

You need to make sure that your repository directory is writeable by the git user itself. (you did make one right?).

[Heres a good resource](https://www.linux.com/learn/how-run-your-own-git-server) to help you clean things up.

Comment: Well I created a folder called mfserver.git and did a git init --bare

Comment: Then I pulled the repo from the server which created the folder mfserver. Both folders have permissions set to writeable

Comment: create everything while assuming the gituser identity that you create first.

Comment: what do you mean by that? The user when creating the mfserver.git was admin

Comment: look at the tutorial I posted

Comment: well.. maybe I don't see it, but didn't i do what the tutorial said?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111016/discussion-between-sesc360-and-devdonkey).